# Automatically refactor code to avoid parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, refactoring, immutability, automated-refactoring

I have a class that has a parameterless constructor that I want to remove (or make private)

```
class C
{
    string A { get; set; }
    int B { get; set; }
    public C() { }    //Problem
    public C(A a, B b)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }
}
```

Problem is, the code base is littered with hundreds of expressions such as `new C {A = a, B = b}`, or `new C() { B = b, A = a }`, in every conceivable variation, ordering of fields, etc. (I didn't know that the brackets were optional until today).
Is there any automated way of fixing up my code to use the 2 argument constructor? The changes are trivial, but I think I'll go insane if I have to do it manually.
My examples have 5 or 6 arguments, and not all are required, etc.

(The motivation is to make the class immutable. Hiding the parameterless constructor and the public setters is the first step)

I've had a small amount of success with regular expressions (Notepad++'s regex support seems to stop after 4 captures), but writing a complex regex to fix 6 items at a time doesn't actually save me a great deal.

Comment: Do you have any code tools available such as Code Rush or ReSharper?

Comment: @Adam - Not sure - I think a colleague has resharper. I'm prepared to consider buying a tool if that's what it takes

Comment: There is a way to do it in ReSharper, but unless you default all the values you'll need to go and correct each caller anyway.

Comment: You can install cygwin and use sed for each case you find over the entire code base. Make sure to check in each compiling refactor to source control! (Knowing how to use sed effectively is an excellent way to become a productive programmer.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ability to explicitly specify [named arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) in a function call (including a constructor) to fix this *relatively* easily.

Specifically, you can replace

```
 C() { B = b, A = a }
```

with

```
 C(B: b, A: a)
```

and the constructor will behave correctly.  This will work regardless of the order of the arguments, so long as they're all either specified or optional.

---

Here's an *entirely* different approach you can try:

Do exactly what you want to do to `C`.  Then create a `CBuilder` class which has all the same properties as a `C`, but only has a single method:

```
public C Convert()
{
   return new C(this.A, this.B);
}
```

Then, you just need to do a find/replace on `new C() {...};` and change it into `(new CBuilder() {...}).Convert();`, which would be a single regex replacement.

This doesn't *immediately* solve the problem, but it does let you refactor freely, and you can make it policy that every time you work on something that uses `CBuilder`, you replace *that instance* of it with a `C` instead.  Gradually, you'll refactor all the code, but it won't prevent you from moving forward.

Comment: Good idea, but our project uses .Net 3.5. Could an automated refactor tool help me convert away from named arguments?

Comment: @Rob - As far as I'm aware, no.  Is upgrading to .NET 4 feasible?  There's a *lot* of nice features you'd gain in the process, and it's relatively painless.  See: [List of breaking changes 3.5 -> 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855831%28VS.100%29.aspx) &  [Migration guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee941656%28VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: Maybe you could make use of named parameters.

new C {A = 5, B = "tt"} is in the end equivalent to new C(A: 5, B: "tt")

So you could replace all occurences of "A =" into "A:" and "B =" into "B :"
This could be easier with temporary rename of A into NewNameForANotCollidingWithAnything so that you can do massive blind automated and safe replace.

Then replace "new C{...}" into new "C (...)" // this is the most difficult part (I did not try it)

Hope it takes you closer to what you need....

Answer (score -1):

Remove your parameterless constructor completely.  The compiler will fail on all it's uses and you can switch to use the 2-parameter version.

Comment: -1 did you read the question? This is exactly what the OP is trying to avoid doing...